# How to group a list so that a single record for a day on a DateTime field is retrived using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of data as shown in the image below.

[image: Dataset]

Now, I want to group the list using Linq in such a way so that I get only 1 record for a day (highlighted) for a particular ID.

The achieve the same goal in MS Excel, I will remove the time part of the LocationDate column, and then remove the duplicates containing ID and LocationDate.

Actually, I need to pick only one location (first preferably) in a day for a particular ID.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Date.Date }) // group by ID and date
                 .Select(x => 
                     // get the first one in each group
                     x.First())
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: You are grouping by date only ignoring the IDs. Assuming the last ID is 164329, I should get 3 records, but your query will return two only. What I need is get a single location per day for a particular ID.

Comment: @RAK Can you provide a larger sample of inputs and outputs? Does the edited answer work?

Comment: I edited the question with more input data and explanation. Your edited answer will not work.

Answer (score 2):

try `var groupby = list.GroupBy(a => new { a.id, a.date }).Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(y=>y.date).First()).ToList();
;`

Comment: That will return the List of Lists. I just want a single list of two records (in the example), completely ignoring others